# Adding classes based on form field validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add classes to my form fields based on the state of the field.

Here's the flow I'm trying to achieve:

1. User see's the form for the first time
2. User clicks on the `first name` form field.
3. User doesn't type anything in the `first name` form field and clicks elsewhere.
4. Add class `.cForm__error` to the `first name` field.
5. User sees `first name` field is empty and clicks on the field to add text.
6. Remove class `.cForm__error` from that field.

Here's my approach so far:

```js
$(function() {

  const form_field = $(".cForm__formField");


  $(form_field).focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("cForm__hasText");
  });

  $(form_field).blur(function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
      $(this).removeClass("cForm__hasText");
    } else{
        $(this).addClass("cForm__error");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.cForm__hasText {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.cForm__error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input class="cForm__formField" type="text" placeholder="first name">
```

Currently, the `.cFrom__hasText` class is appearing, but I need the `.cFrom__error` class to present itself and stay there after initial focus.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just had some of your logic round the wrong way. The below seems to do exactly what you describe. I've assumed you want to add the `cForm__hasText` class when the user types something into the field.

```js
$(function() {

  const form_field = $(".cForm__formField");


  $(form_field).focus(function() {    
    $(this).removeClass("cForm__error");
  });

  $(form_field).blur(function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
       $(this).addClass("cForm__error");
    } else{
      $(this).addClass("cForm__hasText");       
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.cForm__hasText {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.cForm__error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input class="cForm__formField" type="text" placeholder="first name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else in the `blur()` is saying to add the error class  if there ***is*** a value, so it is backwards

You can use `toggleClass(className, boolean)` to cover both cases for the error class

```js
$(function() {

  const $form_field = $(".cForm__formField");


  $form_field.focus(function() {       
    $(this).addClass("cForm__hasText");
  });

  $form_field.blur(function() {   
     const isEmpty = !this.value.trim()
     $(this).removeClass("cForm__hasText")
            .toggleClass("cForm__error", isEmpty);
  });

});
```

```css
.cForm__hasText {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.cForm__error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input class="cForm__formField" type="text" placeholder="first name">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the input after it lost the focus. Also it is necessary to remove one class and add another.

```js
$(function() {
  const form_field = $(".cForm__formField");

  $(form_field).focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("cForm__hasText");
  });

  $(form_field).focusout(function() {
    if (this.value) {
      $(this).addClass("cForm__hasText").removeClass("cForm__error");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("cForm__error").removeClass("cForm__hasText");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cForm__hasText {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.cForm__error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input class="cForm__formField" type="text" placeholder="first name">
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I suggest you use id because it is more precise when triggering an element unlike classes. if you have multiple inputs with the same class, they will all be triggered red because the user didn't fill the first one.

second of all, I suggest using .on() because it waits until all elements on the webpage are rendered. here is an example that will provide you with the desired output

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cForm__formField").on("blur", function(e){
    if(e.target.value === '')
        $("#"+e.target.id).addClass("cForm__formRed");
  })
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qo98vbm/)